# HTACCESS: rewrite a uri request [properties/a-zto myphp php file

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting

My goal is to achieve the following:

**My query:** `properties.php?id=1234-N-StreetName-etc`

**to be turned into:**

```
properties/1234-N-Beverly-Blvd.html
```

`properties.php` will evaluate the value of `$id` (In this case `any-address.html`) against a mysql database. If a value is not in the database, the file properties.php will redirect the user to a 404 page.
**Where $id's value can be any combination of** alphabetical characters, dash '-', or numbers.

The code I have is not working:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ $1.php [nc]
RewriteRule ^properties/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)\.html$ properties.php?id=$1
```

Can you please help me get the right htaccess rewrite-code?

PS. I know nothing about .htaccess. I modified this code form a sample website.

Comment: For future reference, having a property or mailing address as an "id" might become a problem.  Unique ids can be important... :)

Comment: uri.uri_address is a foreign key to a primary key

Comment: That's cool; I just mean... what if you have two things that have the same URL in your browser? ;)

Comment: @summea all my FK are indexed, otherwise they can't be FK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need L flag to mark that rule as **Last** and QSA for **Query String Append**.

Use this code in .htaccess under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^properties/([^.]+)\.html$ /properties.php?id=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

#### To apply this rule in a sub directory sun use this code:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /sub

RewriteRule ^properties/([^.]+)\.html$ /sub/properties.php?id=$1 [L,NC,QSA]

# translate html -> php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)\.html$ /$1.php [L,NC]
```

This will handle URI such as `/sub/properties/abc-123.html` and forward it to `/sub/properties.php?id=abc-123`

Comment: What are the effects of L and QSA?

Comment: Pls check this official doc for details: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriteflags

Comment: Sure you can limit it by using `[a-zA-Z0-9_&-]` instead of `[^.]`

Comment: I am getting a 505 Error =,(

Comment: Ah there is a typo :( `NC,QSA` instead of `NC.QSA` (I mistyped period instead of comma)

Comment: Yea! I no longer get a 505 error. However, I am getting a 404 error =,(

Comment: What URI did you enter in your browser?

Comment: Ok tell me what happens when you enter this URI in browser: `/properties.php?id=123-abc`

Comment: The browser takes me to the file `properties.php` and the php file does it's thing. -For now, while testing uri rewrite, I am just echoing the request $id (`echo $_REQUEST['id'];`)

Comment: Ok that's good then my rule is also doing same i.e. when you enter `properties/123-abc.html ` it will internally load `properties.php?id=123-abc`. Make sure code in .htaccess under DOCUMENT_ROOT directory.

Comment: anubhava Error 404: The requested URL /properties/123-abc.php was not found on this server.

Comment: I got it to work. One last thing. If I want this same rule to apply to just a sub-directory (with it's own `.htaccess` file), what do I do?

Comment: As you can see in my question, I have `RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ $1.php [nc]` which allows me to "mask" php files as HTML. What I had to do is to cancel this line to make it work with your answer. However, I still would like to have this ability.